# mongodb: unknown m/r field for sharding: limit

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, limit, sharding

When I use "limit" in mapreduce sharding collection I see this error: **unknown m/r field for sharding: limit**

**Code**:

```
m = function() { emit(this.user_id, 1); }
r = function(k,vals) { 
 var sum=0;
 for(var i in vals) sum += vals[i];
 return sum; 
}
db.visits.mapReduce(m, r,{out: { inline : 1}, limit: 4});
```

I use mongodb 2.0.2

Yesterday I had 2 servers with sharding and "limit" paramenter worked fine but today I've added 2 more servers, setup a new sharding and got this problem.

Comment: Hey,
Are you running these mapreduce functions from a driver or via the shell directly? Does it give any other errors when you run it without the limit option?

Answer (score 0):

The `limit` option is currently unsupported for sharded map-reduce:
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2099

I'm not sure how it would have worked against just two shards. It shouldn't have, unless you were connecting directly to a single shard.